# How can I make the instances of my SuperCounter class stop counting independently?

Tags: javascript, class, setinterval

I just created a counter class that seems to work almost okay.
Unfortunately there is an issue that I cannot identify.
I instance my class twice with a different name but the parameters remain the same in terms of the chrono max limit.
Thanks to anyone who could help me...

I'm trying to create a class that can display a counter but there is a problem with the parameters. Of course I could just create a simple function instead but that's not what I'm trying to do. I would like to stay in the same perspective if possible... Thanks to anyone who could help me...

I'll let you look at the code a little further down.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});

class SuperCounter {
  constructor(cumul, limit) {
    this.cumul = cumul;
    this.limit = limit;
  }
  add() {
    if (this.cumul === this.limit) {
      console.warn('Counter just reached to the limit');
      clearInterval(ignition)
    };
    return {
      result: this.cumul++,
      //limit: this.limit,
    }
  }
}

const firstCounter = new SuperCounter(1, 50);
const secondCounter = new SuperCounter(1, 150);

const ignition = setInterval(displayCounter, 100);

function displayCounter() {
  document.querySelector("#chrono1").innerHTML = /*html*/ `<h2>Chrono #1 : ${firstCounter.add().result}</h2>`
  document.querySelector("#chrono2").innerHTML = /*html*/ `<h2>Chrono #2 : ${secondCounter.add().result}</h2>`
};
```

```html
<h3 id="chrono1"></h3>
<h3 id="chrono2"></h3>
```

Comment: You only have 1 `setInterval` created that's shared by both instance. So when you clear it for the first it will stop running for the second. Also, please try and update your question title with something that people with a similar problem in the future will be able to search and find.

Comment: You shared two pieces of code. Which is the one you are asking about? It is a bit strange to start your post with a code snippet without explanation, and then you start talking about a counter class. Is that the one above or below? Please clarify.

Comment: Please [post your solution as an answer](/help/self-answer), not as an edit to your question.

Comment: @trincot I've rolled back the confusing edits

Comment: Ok sorry guys, I'm not really used to it, I'll try to do better in the future

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that you are calling `clearInterval()` from within your `SuperCounter.add()` method. What if a `SuperCounter` object is being used *independently* of a `setInterval()`?

As you want to trigger the `add()` method of your counters in a synchronized way (in one common `setInterval()` callback-function) and you want that function to be called repeatedly until both counters have reached their limits you should only call `clearInterval(ignition)` after *both* counters are `.done`. This property is set as soon as the limit of the counter has been reached.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});

class SuperCounter {
  constructor(cumul, limit) {
    this.cumul = cumul-1;
    this.limit = limit;
  }
  add() {
    if (this.cumul == this.limit){
      if(!this.done){
        console.warn('Counter just reached its limit '+this.limit);
        this.done=true;
      }
    } else this.cumul++;
    return this.cumul;
  }
}

const firstCounter = new SuperCounter(1, 50);
const secondCounter = new SuperCounter(81, 150);

const ignition = setInterval(displayCounter, 100);

function displayCounter() {
  document.querySelector("#chrono1").innerHTML = /*html*/ `<h2>Chrono #1 : ${firstCounter.add()}</h2>`
  document.querySelector("#chrono2").innerHTML = /*html*/ `<h2>Chrono #2 : ${secondCounter.add()}</h2>`
  if(firstCounter.done&&secondCounter.done) clearInterval(ignition);
};
```

```html
<h3 id="chrono1"></h3>
<h3 id="chrono2"></h3>
```

I also took the liberty of simplifying the return value of your `add()` method to the current counter value. And, in order to make the demo a little faster, I started the second counter at value 81 ;-).

Comment: Ok Carsten I understand your explanations, honestly I didn't even think about it at the moment...
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use class syntax (ever - [why not?](https://medium.com/@araujjohnny/stop-using-javascript-classes-d0b6890ef097)). Using `setTimeout` will give more control to the loop. Here is a demo counter [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) function (replacing the class syntax) for some independent counters:

```js
SuperCounterFactory(document.querySelector(`#cntr1`)).start();
SuperCounterFactory(document.querySelector(`#cntr2`)).start();
const cntr3 = SuperCounterFactory(document.querySelector(`#cntr3`));
cntr3.start();

setTimeout( () => {
  cntr3.reset(); 
  cntr3.start(); }, 25_000);

function SuperCounterFactory(elem) {
  const interval = +elem.dataset.interval ?? 1;
  let [value, limit] = init();
  
  function stop() {
    console.log(`counter for #${elem.id} done`); 
    value = limit; 
  };
  
  function start() {
    value += 1;
    elem.dataset.cnt = value;
    
    if (value < limit) {
      return setTimeout(start, interval * 1000);
    }
    
    return stop();
  }
  
  function init() {
    elem.dataset.from = elem.dataset.from ?? 0;
    elem.dataset.to = elem.dataset.to ?? 100;
    elem.dataset.cnt = elem.dataset.from;
    return [+elem.dataset.cnt, +elem.dataset.to];
  }
  
  function reset() {
    console.log(`reset counter for #${elem.id}`);
    elem.dataset.cnt = 0;
    [value, limit] = init();
  }
  
  return { start, reset };
}
```

```css
[data-cnt]:after {
  content: attr(data-cnt);
}
```

```html
<div id="cntr1" data-from="10" data-to="75" data-interval="0.15"></div>
<div id="cntr2" data-interval="0.25"></div>
<div id="cntr3" data-to="50" data-interval="0.4"></div>
```